# Answer box cursor broke

Tags: bug, answers

I just went to answer a question and my cursor is moved one space over to the left for some reason. Here's an image of it (I just pressed space before taking the screenshot, I didn't move the cursor):

[image: cursor is to the left of the character instead of to the right]

In case its important I was answering my own question and the bold text in the  tag was acting fine.

Comment: What browser are you using? What operating system?

Comment: chrome and windows 10

Comment: I tried to download the HTML of the page but when I opened it there was no text in the answer box.